# Show header text on top when using wrapped headers

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with some columns like this:

```
columns: [
    {
        title: 'Test',
        field: 'SomeField',
        width: '200px'
    },
    {
        title: 'Extra long example title',
        field: 'SomeOtherField',
        width: '100px',
        headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal" }
    },
    ...
]
```

My long title gets wrapped without any problems. But every shorter column title that doesn't need to get wrapped is shown at the bottom of the header like this:

```
+------------+------------+
|            | Extra long |
|            | example    |
| Test       | title      |
+------------+------------+
```

However, I'd like to have the title at the top of the header like this:

```
+------------+------------+
| Test       | Extra long |
|            | example    |
|            | title      |
+------------+------------+
```

I tried adding `headerAttributes: { style: "margin-top: 0" }` to the first column but it didn't change anything. How could I achieve this?

Comment: vertical-align:top ?

Comment: @ArtemKh Omg yes, didn't think of that...

Comment: @ArtemKh Please post it as answer to get the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of ArtemKh was the solution to my problem. I just had to add `vertical-align: top` to my `headerAttributes` to show the headers on top of the cell.